# Properly addressing "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )" error

Tags: javascript

In my console I am getting the

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

I know why I am getting this error but, not sure how to resolve it as all of the methods I have tried have not been successful.

This is the snippet of code it is in.

```
var contentDetails = '<div id="iw-container">'+
                                     '<div class="iw-title">' + ((value.streamStatus == 'true') ? ('<span class="online"><i class="material-icons" style="vertical-align:-3px; font-size:18px;">videocam</i></span> ') : ('<span class="offline"><i class="material-icons" style="vertical-align:-3px; font-size:18px;">videocam_off</i></span><strong> ' )) + value.DisplayName + ' - ' + value.ChaserLocation + '</strong><hr /></div>'+
                                     '<div class="iw-content">'+
                                     '<p>Location: ' + value.UserLocation + '<br />'+
                                     'Heading: ' + value.UserHeading + '<br />'+
                                     ((value.streamStatus == 'true') ? ('Stream: <span class="online">Online</span><br />') : ('Stream: <span class="offline">Offline</span><br />'))+
                                     ((value.streamStatus == 'true') ? ('Viewers: ' + value.CurrentViewers + ))+
                                     '</div>';
```

The specific line of interest where the error is come from is the second to last.

```
((value.streamStatus == 'true') ? ('Viewers: ' + value.CurrentViewers + ))+
```

Any assistance with how I can properly close this line?

Comment: Is something supposed to come after `value.CurrentViewers`?

Comment: Look closely at  `+ ))+` in the line of interest.

Comment: Besides the syntax error caused by  `+ ))`, in the incriminated line `?` is a marking point for a ternary operation. It expects `firstValue : secondValue` but here there is no `: secondValue` passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update from this:

```
((value.streamStatus == 'true') ? ('Viewers: ' + value.CurrentViewers + ))
```

To this:

```
((value.streamStatus == 'true') ? ('Viewers: ' + value.CurrentViewers) : '')
```

The 2 changes are adding the "false" option in the ternary expression and removing the extra "+"

Comment: This method would print out 'something and 'something' though correct? If that is the case that would not work for me as nothing is suppose to come after `value.CurrentViewers`

Comment: You can print out anything you want - point was to complete the ternary expression. I've updated to include empty string and remove unneeded "+"

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. I hate my server has varnish caching enabled. I guess when I tried this before it didn't work but it seems to work now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
var contentDetails = []
contentDetails.push ( '<div id="iw-container">' )
contentDetails.push ( '<div class="iw-title">' )
contentDetails.push ( (value.streamStatus == 'true') ? '<span class="online"><i class="material-icons" style="vertical-align:-3px; font-size:18px;">videocam</i></span> ' : '<span class="offline"><i class="material-icons" style="vertical-align:-3px; font-size:18px;">videocam_off</i></span><strong> ' + value.DisplayName + ' - ' + value.ChaserLocation + '</strong><hr /></div>' )
contentDetails.push ( '<div class="iw-content">' )
contentDetails.push ( '<p>Location: ' + value.UserLocation + '<br />' )
contentDetails.push ( 'Heading: ' + value.UserHeading + '<br />' )
contentDetails.push ( (value.streamStatus == 'true') ?'Stream: <span class="online">Online</span><br />':'Stream: <span class="offline">Offline</span><br />')
contentDetails.push ( value.streamStatus == 'true' ? 'Viewers: ' + value.CurrentViewers : '')
contentDetails.push ( '</div>' )
contentDetails = contentDetails.join('')
```